# Not able to pass this object value in another method

Tags: javascript

while getting this object in javascript its coming blank. Hence not able to pass that value to another method. For reference I am placing my codes:

while calling the method:

```
    getFlag(this,'callMethod','parameter');
```

Method:

```
    function getFlag(obj,meth,para){
```

//Here getting obj as blank. So not able to form the methName properly.

```
var methName = meth+"("+obj+","+"\'"+para+"\')";
setTimeout(methName,1);


    }

    function callMethod(thisobj,val){
    //Some code
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If function `callMethod` is defined globally, you can try with:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  window[meth](obj, para);
},1);
```